# Limits of the function and its integral $f_n(t)$ where $n=2^k+p$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $n=2^k+p$ where $0\le p<2^k$ and let $f_n(t)$ be a sequence of functions from $[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as:
$$f_n(t)=\begin{cases}1,\ \ \ \ t\in[\frac{p}{2^k},\frac{p+1}{2^k})\\0,\ \ \ \ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then, how do we find $\int_0^1 |f_n(t)|dt$ and $\limsup,\liminf$ of $f_n(t)$ as $n\to\infty$?

I am totally confused by this problem. As $n\to\infty$, will not both $k,p$ also tend to infinity? Is $\limsup=1$ and $\liminf=0$? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n$ there is a unique $k$ and $p$ such that $n=2^{k}+p$ and $0\leq p<2^{k}$. In fact, $k=[\frac {\ln n} {\ln 2}]$. For a given $n$ $f_n$ is simply the characterestic function of the interval $[\frac p {2^{k}}, \frac {p+1} {2^{k}})$ so $\int_0^{1} |f(t)| \, dt =\frac 1 {2^{k}}$ where $k=[\frac {\ln n} {\ln 2}]$. For the second part the answer is $\lim \inf f_n(t)=0$ for all $t$. For $t=0$ this is obvious. Let $0<t<1$. If $j$ is any positive integer such that $\frac 1 {2^{j}} <t$ let $n_j=[2^{j}+t2^{j-1}]$. You can verify that $f_{n_{j}} (t)=0$; in fact, $t >  \frac {p+1} {2^{k}}$ if $k$ and $p$ correspond to $n=n_j$. If you verify this you are done: $f_n (t)=0$ for infinitely many $n$ so $\lim \inf f_n(t)=0$. I will leave the verification to you.

PS: as $n \to \infty$ it is true that $k \to \infty$ but $p$ need not tend to $\infty$. In fact we can have $p=0$ for a sequence of integers $n$ tending to $\infty$.

Comment: how is $k=[\frac{ln\ n}{ln\ 2}]$? do you mean $[\ \ ]$ to be the floor function?

Comment: Yes, $[.]$ is the floor function. $k$ is determined by the inequalities $2^{k} \leq n <2^{k+1}$  and taking logarithms you c an find the value of $k$ in terms of $n$.

Comment: and $\limsup=1$ right?

Comment: True. $\lim \sup f_n(t)=1$ if $ t>0$ but $\lim \sup f_n(t)=0$ if $ t=0$.